# Has the division on all four sites affected SO?

Tags: discussion, subjective, stack-exchange

I noticed that on SO there are now questions without answers and low views for much longer than when only SO existed.

Are people hanging out more on meta (like me now for example), or SU?

Do you think this will hurt the great quality of answers one could get on SO?

Comment: Reading this very question is keeping people from reading SO instead.  Look what you've done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I think it helped SO.  SO has aquired a large base of users and has a lot of content now.  The division keeps SO more focused. Every site has a purpose.  I would hang on meta if I want to ask or check out meta related questions and the same for all the others.

I think you hang out in the site with the most topics you deal with the most often or maybe the one you know the best.

Comment: Well the base of content is good if your issue has been covered before, but it's possible that the multiplication of sites has caused fewer people to answer *new* questions on SO.

Answer (score 3):

StackOverflow is still monstrously busy compared to SuperUser.

In my opinion SU is going to suffer because it's discussion is SO unfocused. Almost any question appears to be fair game, and when something is closed, it seems arbitrary and contradictory, because there's 13 similar questions still open.

Comment: It took a little while for the community (and Jeff) to decide which questions were acceptable and which weren't. So there could well be some "unacceptable" questions lurking in the bushes (so to speak).

Comment: SU in the future will see a lot of content

Comment: SU just needs more folks with Mod access...  That'll help....